# Цикл for и гистограмма символов

Tags: c

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в вопросе. Эту программу я нашел в интернете, она высчитывает гистограмму некоторых символов и ставить вертикальные столбцы. Если с объявлением массива и инкриминированием индексов все понятно. Я в своей программе точно также и сделал, то не очень понятна часть, где выводится массив.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c, j, i;
    int characters[5];

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        characters[i] = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '}')
            ++characters[0];
        if (c == '=')
            ++characters[1];
        if (c == '[')
            ++characters[2];
        if (c == '+')
            ++characters[3];
        if (c == ';')
            ++characters[4];
    }

    printf("}t\=\t[\t+\t;\t\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
            if (i < characters[j])
                printf("*\t");
            else
                printf(" \t");
            if (j == 4)
                printf("\n");
        }
}
```

Я так понимаю, что тело цикла `for (i = 0; i < 30; ++i)` включает себя цикл `for (j = 0; j < 5; ++j)` и все операторы, которые входят соответственно в его тело. Дальше идет очень странное сравнение переменная счетчика сравнивается с индексом массива. То есть если сравнивается `i=1` и `j=1`, то `j=1`, которая будет содержать пять `}}}}}` будет больше и легко подобрать такую комбинацию в результате, которой звездочки, обозначающие длину не печатались. В общем данный стиль абсолютно не понятен. Вы не могли задать несколько наводящих подсказок о том, как сделать грамотный вертикальный вывод гистограммы? Я пытаюсь пройти задания Кернигана и Ричи.

Comment: Где Вы это 

    очень странное сравнение переменная счетчика сравнивается с индексом массива

увидели?

IMHO номер строки (переменная i) сравнивается с количеством символов типа j (i < **characters**[j]). Если меньше - печатаем звездочку.

Единственно, я бы выбросил if(j==4) и вытащил printf("\\n"); во внешний цикл.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Со всем разобрался!